# Redirects not working with OOTB web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

From the defauly ASP.Net Web application when clicking on the links on the layout page instead of being directed to

```
Home/Contact
```

I am getting redirected to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:49823/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fContact
```

I had the following section in web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

This was blocking access to even the register page so I changed the deny to allow

Comment: What type of MVC 4 project did you select?  That URL is the normal one you'd be redirected to if you needed to login to view the page.

Comment: Internet Application, it should be directing to Home/Contact and Account/Register etc

Comment: Do you have an Authorize attribute on the Home controller or the Contact action?  It looks like forms authentication is kicking in because you are not logged in and it thinks that route requires authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part

```
<authorization>
 <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and use the authorize attribute